# How to make width 100% of browser in a div?

Tags: html, css, browser, width, parent-child

I basically have a contents div which is set to a width of 1000. In my contents div, I also have a footer div. WHen i set the footer div to width:100%, then the footer width will be as large as the contents div. How do I make my footer scale to 100% of my browser window if it is already in a div?

Comment: You could take footer out of the contents div, as the simplest solution

Comment: Is this the normal way that footers are implemented?. Also do you you still put all the footer contents in the contents div or do I put footer contents in the footer div?

Comment: Depends on how you want your site. But generally, footers are outside or wrapper dibs so they can be full width. All the footer content will be outside the wrapper doc, and in its own container. Take a look at www.bellavou.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

**Better move footer out from container.**

But if you really need this, there is work, but fragile solution:

```
.parent{
    position: static;
}
```

**All** parents to element with 100% width must be static. And this can break something else, because `position: relative` is often useful.

```
.closest_el_width_100_percent_width{
    position: relative;
}
```

And footer itself:

```
footer:{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0
}
```

Add, paddings, margins, salt and pepper by you taste.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9rjskuon/

Answer (score 0):

You can always use "vw" instead of % (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)
 so  at the end you can use

```
.footer{
    width: 100vw;
}
```

and then position it wherewer you need, but you shouldnt need this for footer. firstly you should place your footer out of your wrapper.